# Основы Java: создание объектов

Tags: java

Изучаю Java. Однако не могу освоить самого простого - создание объектов.

Для примера:

```
class Shape{
    int square=5;
    Shape(){System.out.println("Shape constructor");};
    void draw(){System.out.println("Shape draw()");};
}

class Circle extends Shape{
    int radius=5;
    Circle(){System.out.println("Circle constructor");};
    void clear(){};
    void draw(){System.out.println("Circle draw()");};  
}

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape s=new Circle();
        s.draw();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

`Shape s=new Circle();` - `s` будет ссылкой на какой объект?

`new Circle()` – создаст и инициализирует объект Circle, то есть фактически выделит память под int square и int radius и инициализирует их значениями «5».

- s – будет содержать ссылку на вновь
     созданный объект, то есть на область
     памяти с данными (полями). **А значит
     s ссылка на объект Circle.**
- Shape s – указывает, что s ссылка на
     объект типа Shape. Соответственно и
     методы доступны только базового
     класса. **А значит s ссылка на объект
     Shape.**
- s.draw() – отрабатывает метод класса
     Circle. **А значит s - объект с
     полями Circle, доступными методами
     Shape, но отрабатывают методы
     Circle.**

Comment: @vanam, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 7):

Есть такая штука в ООП (и в Java тоже). Называется позднее связывание. Оно нужно для того, чтобы определить, какой именно метод стоит вызывать в подобных случаях. Если коротко, то в зависимости от фактического типа объекта вызывается подходящий метод. По факту у вас тип объекта - Circle. Следовательно, вызываться будет именно метод этого типа как наиболее подходящий, несмотря на то, что при объявлении типа указано Shape.
В этом есть своя логика. Если брать ваш пример, являющийся хрестоматийным примером демонстрации полиморфизма - базовый класс Shape и производные от него Circle и прочие, то вполне логично ожидать, что раз вы вызываете у конкретного Circle метод draw, то должна быть нарисована именно окружность (что еще можно ожидать, вызывая этот метод у экземпляра класса Circle?). И это весьма удобно - у вас может быть несколько "фигур", каждая из которых сама "знает" как себя рисовать, и вы можете эти несколько фигур использовать одинаково и при этом получать корректный результат.

Стоит также отметить, что позднее связывание обычно реализуется с помощью таблицы виртуальных методов, почитайте про нее.